# Django-tastypie. More human-readable JSON in the browser

Tags: django, tastypie

Can I get a more human-readable JSON in the browser? More formatted
and beautiful output...

Thanks,
Vitaliy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Safari - https://github.com/rfletcher/safari-json-formatter
- Firefox - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/
- Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc

Answer (score 0):

Postman Chrome plugin. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fofkknmmmfkaddpcncigehnadkalmhhj

So you can test the rest of the REST api.